# Страна-законодательница и ее культура

Tags: грамотная-речь

Страна, культура которой пользуется спросом в других странах, может называться "Законодателем культуры" или сочетание нелепо? Оно почти равно сочетанию "Законодатель культурных тенденций"? Какое предпочтительнее и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что первое сочетание вполне уместно, но не подходит чисто логически. В моем понимании культура представляет собой нечто общее, сложившееся достаточно давно и имеющее определённый вид, который можно, например, немного изменить, но не **переделать полностью**. Отсюда я больше предпочитаю сочетание "культурные тенденции", подчёркивающее определённые направления культуры, но не её саму.

**Примечание**: логика выстроена с учётом того, что одна страна мировую культуру изменить не может.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, "законодатель культуры" звучит нелепо. Можно сказать, например, "законодатель мод", потому что "законы моды" являются вполне допустимым выражением. Но что такое "законы культуры"?